# Delete Only My webbrowser Cache

Tags: vb.net

in my my application i have webbrowser control, i don't want that users trace my web address, Because when i got to internet explorer in the history panel i found my website; Already on the list.
by using windows shell command they Will kill the whole user history; also they show me dialog box. it's not professional at All; 
i mean this Command Line :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1")
```

So i would like to have solution form you masters how to remove only my entry for exemple : www.XXXXXXX.Net
Thank you best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do may not be possible, check this link:

A quote from the answer provided by MSDN support at the link:

"Microsoft hasn't provided methods or events for users to iterate or clear the URL navigation history. But with the events already provided, like Navigated, Navigating, you could implement your own navigation history class to log or clear the history."

There are also other links on the thread that may help you to develop a solution.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dded6546-6e22-4542-b29f-7d0e1ec048a1/clear-browser-history-in-webbrowser-control?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Link only answers can go missing and then become stale. It would be beneficial to expain the information pertained in the link to help make this answer more useful.